# Fetching default region on aws from api

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to fetch the default region your on aws using the aws api? Im currently using the golang aws sdk

Comment: The documentation on AWS is a bit messy, I prefer something like https://godoc.org/github.com/crowdmob/goamz/aws, but why do you need the code to get your default region? Just specify your default region (which you should know given it's your aws account) in a variable and pass that around the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about golang but in the CLI:

```
aws configure list
```

Your account doesn't have a default region per se.  The default region is particular to a client (such as your browser; when you select a region it's saved to a cookie or maybe local storage).

Comment: This is correct.  There is no concept of a default region on an AWS account.  The console defaults to the last region you were viewing, and clients may be configured with (or have hard-coded) default regions, but the account has no such concept.

Comment: Thank you this was what I needed to understand